# fix blurry OLE images in Microsoft Visio 2010

Tags: microsoft-visio

When I paste an image from MSPaint into Visio 2010 it goes slightly blurryno matter what the zoom level is at.
Here is a comparison:

[image]

I dont know if Visio is converting it to jpg, which causes such blurryness, but it has also made the green border thicker on two sides and thinner on the other two than the orginal image on the left.

Is there some settings in Visio to enable it to paste and display graphics more clearer?.

Note: using the insert button in visio sort of works but the image is still blurry, the lines are the correct thickness though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that has been discussed on the Microsoft Visio forums. Here is one thread that might help you.

[Copied images from clipboard are always blurred on Microsoft Visio forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/161584d7-2c8d-40c2-8737-c34c5abb9bde/copied-images-from-clipboard-are-always-blurred-i-cannot-change-this-in-the-visio-options-anymore?forum=visiogeneral)